# Confusing behavior of Redirect in React-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My version of react-router-dom is 4.3.1, below is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from '../../pages/Layout';
import Home from '../../pages/Home';
import BoatsManager from '../../pages/BoatsManager'; 

export const routes = [
    { path: '/home', component: Home },
    { path: '/boatsManager', component: BoatsManager }
];
 
export default function Router () {

 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
          <Switch>   
              <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
              {
                                routes.map(route =>
                                    <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} 
                                     component={route.component} />
                         )
                       
              }
                        </Switch>    
     </Layout>
  </BrowserRouter>

  )
}
```

The issue is If I delete exact from Redirect component like

```
 <Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
```

then when I go to path /home or /boatsManager, the corresponding component will not be rendered, if I add exact into Redirect, they will be rendered. I think if I do not add exact, both /home and /boatsManager will be redirected to /home, but at least the component with the path /home should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is with the key property. You're setting the key property for both component routes. But when you set redirect from `/` to `/home`, it helps to go to the `/home` path but the navigation history `/` which have no key and this has no component bound and this will be rendering the blank page. To fix,

```
<Redirect key="/home" from="/" to="/home" />
```

Now, this matches the navigation history and will render the component.

Note: when you don't you use exact property all of your routing will go to the `/home`.